# SKIO calculus solver?

Tags: math

At the Googology wiki, there is a function called the Xi function, based on SKIO calculus.https://googology.wikia.org/wiki/Xi_function  I found that they calculated Xi(7) as 51 (my program can go to the #s  up to and including six because they don't have the oracle combinator). I  am wondering if there is a program that I can use to solve this problem as a curiosity of trying to find the 8th Xi number.

Note: The original SKI calculus could be found at https://github.com/adidahiya/SKI-Calculus/ and the Xi function link was a description of what it is and why I want to play with it.